# Do I have to make separate layout for tabs?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabs

I am having a problem while making an app. Here's my xml Layout which is working fine on small screen but not working proper on Tabs.How How can I adjust the layout to make common for all screens. Also I would like to know that I have set textbox height in dps,w.r.t small screen(default one),but it is not occuping proper space in tab.So I can adjust it?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:background="#ffffffff">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.55"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:background="#1E90FF">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:background="@drawable/lock"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Login"

            android:id="@+id/textView11"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton8"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/f_icon"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView11"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.45">




        <EditText
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/editText10"
            android:background="@drawable/edittextstyle"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/textboxuser"

            android:drawablePadding="2dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dip"
            android:paddingRight="26dip"
            android:hint="Username"
            android:singleLine="true"

            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="#ff464646"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:ems="10"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:paddingRight="26dip"
            android:background="@drawable/edittextstyle"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/textboxpwd"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/editText11"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="Sign In"
            android:background="#1E90FF"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Forgot Password !! Click Here"

            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:textColor="#ff424242"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="68dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="Not a member yet? Join Now"
            android:onClick="register"
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:textColor="#fffcfffa"

            android:clickable="true"


            android:background="#ff000000" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can design intelligently to somehow look your layout more or less okey on all screen sizes then its ok. But normally you should create different layouts for different screen sizes like

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml              // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml        // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml       // layout for extra-large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml
```

For tablet you can declare separate layout like

```
res/layout/main_activity.xml           # For handsets
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For tablets
```

But above all go through android developers website. Read all details. You will get all the info in more structural way

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

**EDIT:**

The configuration qualifiers you can use to provide size-specific resources are small, normal, large, and xlarge. For example, layouts for an extra-large screen should go in layout-xlarge/.
Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), the above size groups are deprecated and you should instead use the swdp configuration qualifier to define the smallest available width required by your layout resources.

```
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For tablets
```

Comment: Thanks for help. So basically the approach is to find the screen resolution at onCreate and then set the layout accordingly. Am I going right in this way?

Comment: Actually android will automatically detect the layout according to screen size. You need not to set it manually. Just keep the folders name same.

Comment: I am just confused know.Let say I have this xml layout. but in Tab(nexus 7(800x1280)) it is not working proproperly. So now I have to select a different layout fot this tab and put it in res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml. And going this way so on,using different resolutions.

Comment: Yes right. but above API 3.2 the folder name will be `layout-sw600dp` instead of `xlarge`. i think you get it.

Comment: Thanks so much, so how many many folders I have to make so to run my app on almost all screen sizes and with which resolution?

Comment: beside main layout large,xlarge and xlarge-land is enough. You can as many as you want for different resolution and orientation. No problem. Again saying go through the android developers website. Give a detail read. That will give you complete idea.

Answer (score 0):

Android also supports multiple versions of res/values based on size, screen orientation and many other configuration qualifiers:

```
res/values/dimens.xml
res/values-large/dimens.xml
res/values-xlarge/dimens.xml
res/values-xlarge-land/dimens.xml
```

In every dimens.xml you can put dimensions to use later in layouts

example view:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="@dimen/edit_text_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/edit_text_height" />
```

values/dimens.xml:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="edit_text_width">120dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="edit_text_height">200dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

values/dimens-large.xml:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="edit_text_width">240dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="edit_text_height">300dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

It is often all you need to support many screen sizes, so it's worth checking